# How to display multiple records with same id on table with Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, user-interface, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a json response with following structure;
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

[I need to display the table on a attached image  structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xdo3x.png).

What I have done is below but it is displaying as user Id repeats. What I need to do for getting my output structure..?

```
  <table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" class="row-border hover">
      <thead>
      <tr>
      <td>Sl No</td>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Body</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let record of dataString;let i=index">
      <td>{{record.userId}}</td>
      <td>{{record.title}}</td>
      <td>{{record.body}}</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need parse your api result and create a new object with the data that you want. Example, do a 'group by' using array methods.

A example object can be user -> id: number, articles: article[]

```
public getUsers(): User[] {
    return this.http.get(URL).map(results => {
        const users: number[] = results
            .filter((item, index, self) => self.indexOf(item.userId) === index)
            .map(item => {
                return {
                    id: item.userId,
                    articles: results.filter(result => result.userId === item.userId)
                        .map(result => {
                            return {
                                id: result.id,
                                title: result.title,
                                body: result.body
                            } as Article
                        })
                } as User
            });
    })
}
```

Comment: Map the api result, in the client. You will obtain a observable from api call, witch you can map the result to a new class or interface, example using map operator.
Example, httpClient.get(URL).map(result => .... return new User(...));

Comment: Update with example

Comment: Go the error "Type 'Observable<void>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Apiresponse[]>'" while applying this